# How do I open a SQL Server database read-only?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a windows service writing to a single-table SQL Server database (2008).

I want another application to read the table in read-only mode.

What do I have to do to open the database appropriately by the application so it's read-only?

Any changes to the way the service opens the database?

Obviously I can't ALTER the database to read-only as the service has to write to it.

Comment: I believe that accessing the database is the same, using SqlConnection. I think the only problem is when you try to insert,update,delete or alter table, then you will get an SqlException.

Comment: I don't understand why the topic was closed.  This was a programming question:  I had an existing windows service. I was in the process of modifying another program to read the database that the windows service writes to, and I wanted to make sure that that program could access to that database.  As it turns out the 2 answers that I received below were helpful, but Mythul's comment hit the nail on the head.  I did nothing differently.  I just didn't try to write to the database and everything worked out fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No changes to the service are necessary.  Just supply a login that has only been granted the db_reader role.  If you have any stored procedures you'll have to grant access to those with the `GRANT EXEC ON <proc> TO <user>` command.

Answer (score 1):

Have that application connect with a user who only has the db_datareader role, discovered @ Server Fault:

> Under Security > Logins, create a new login, and in the User Mapping
>   section, tick the two databases, and for each select db_datareader
>   role membership.
>
> This will provide read access to all the data in each DB.
>
> ...

https://serverfault.com/a/116273